# CAS proxy authentication IOU and ticket

Tags: authentication, cas

I am planning to use [Apero CAS v5](https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas) to authenticate applications (A) which might need to access protected web services (S) as dexcribed [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/installation/Configuring-Proxy-Authentication.html#use-case)

Accroding to the [CAS protocol](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html#proxy-web-flow-diagram) description  `PGTIOU` ticket is delivered to application (A) in response for `serviceValidate` request, and the mapping of `PGTIOU` to `PGT` ticket is given to `pgtUrl` link (given as parameter for `serviceValidate` request).

1. What is the purpose of PGTIOU ticket and how does it improve the security?
2. How can I configure PGT to be delivered in validation response as mentioned [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/installation/Configuring-Proxy-Authentication.html#returning-pgt-in-validation-response)? 
   I have tried adding my application keypair (deployed in tomcat along with cas) to `cas/WEB-INF/classes/truststore.jks`. The same is also added java default keystore (`"$JAVA_HOME"/jre/lib/security/cacerts`)